# Ignore header in join command (outdated coreutils)

Tags: bash, shell, join, gnu-coreutils

I have two CSV files to be joined on a column, I am using unix `join` command, I want to ignore the header while joining, I was using `--header` option in GNU core utils v8.21, but my product machine has core utils v8.4, `--header` is not available in GNU core utils 8.4, I cannot upgrade the core utils in production machine. Is there a way to skip the header(first line and join the files)

```
join --header -t, -1 3 -2 2 <File1> <File2> -o 2.1,1.2,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7
```

Comment: What operating system do you use? I'm in severe doubts that is actually is GNU Unix.

Comment: Openshift environment Redhat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't use `--header`, help yourself out with `tail`

```
join <(tail -n+2 file1) <(tail -n+2 file2)
```